# What does the model prefix P mean on an ipod mini?

Tags: ipod-classic

I have two 2nd generation ipod minis, one green and one blue.

One lists itself as model P9802B and one as M9806B.

I know the last numerical digit indicates the colour, but what did the P or M prefix indicate?

Apple's website only lists the M variant.

One is the iPods is personalised.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you asked and answered your own question. (P = personalized.)